# Passing PHP select elements into a url

Tags: php

Ok so I have a simple php select script and I have the code below to define variables.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM practice_sheets WHERE student_name='$_SESSION[SESS_FIRST_NAME] $_SESSION[SESS_LAST_NAME]'");

   $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   $id = $row['id'];
   $total_min = $row['total_min'];
   $due_date = $row['due_date'];
```

I then have:

`echo "<td> <a href='account/practiceSheets?id='$id'> <i class='icon-eye-open'> </i> </a> </td>";`

and this is supposed to pass the variables from the php select script into the url when the `<a>` is clicked.

All I end up with is the `account/practiceSheets?id=` with no actual id. I'm sure this is something stupidly simple and I do apologize as I am new to PHP and also didn't know what to call this to get a useable result in search engines! My full code is below if it helps.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("50.63.106.47", "usd309bands", "MacBook1!", "usd309bands");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM practice_sheets

 WHERE student_name='$_SESSION[SESS_FIRST_NAME] $_SESSION[SESS_LAST_NAME]'");

 $numrows   = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $id        = $row['id'];
 $total_min = $row['total_min'];
 $due_date  = $row['due_date'];

 if ($numrows == 0) {
   echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
   echo "No Entries, See your instructor for details.";
   echo "</div>";
 } else {

   echo "<table class='mws-table table-striped table-hover'>";
   echo "<thead align='center'>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>Sheet Number</th>";
   echo "<th>Total Minutes</th>";
   echo "<th>Due Date</th>";
   echo "<th>View</th>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</thead>";
   echo "<tbody align='center'>";

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['total_min'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['due_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='account/practiceSheets?id='$id'> <i class='icon-eye-open'> </i>  </a> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
     echo "</tbody>";
     echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: please reformat your code

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean to hit submit :( sorry!!

Comment: One thing... you need to concatenate the value into the string -- exactly like you're doing in other parts of the same code: `echo "<td> <a href='account/practiceSheets?id=".$id."\"> <i class='icon-eye-open'> </i> </a> </td>";` (there are other ways to do this, see the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) You've got an extra single-quote in there.

Comment: $row is never defined

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM practice_sheets
                                                    WHERE student_name='$_SESSION[SESS_FIRST_NAME] $_SESSION[SESS_LAST_NAME]'");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$id = $row['id'];
```

Can't see the where the `$row` is coming from.

I think you've forgotten to fetch the MySQL response into an associated array.
(You could use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to acomplish that)

Here's a quick example:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM practice_sheets WHERE student_name='$_SESSION[SESS_FIRST_NAME] $_SESSION[SESS_LAST_NAME]'");
$allRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach($allRows as $row) {
  echo $row['id'].'<br/>';
}
```

This one should list all ID's from the database request.

Comment: Can you update your answer with code showing the use of the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` I tried adding this and received errors. Assuming I placed it in the wrong area.

Comment: Added a small example, hope it clarifies stuff.

Comment: Still not getting anywhere. Not sure what I am doing wrong, copied your code into mine and got gibberish.

Comment: What do you mean by 'gibberish'? Did it print the IDs?

Answer (score 0):

This sql query is probably not going to return anything unless names are stored in your table like this

firstlast

```
"SELECT * FROM practice_sheets WHERE student_name='$_SESSION[SESS_FIRST_NAME] $_SESSION[SESS_LAST_NAME]'"
```

you probably want something like this

```
$_SESSION[SESS_FIRST_NAME] . " " . $_SESSION[SESS_LAST_NAME]
```

to return a name like

first last

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
echo "<td> <a href='account/practiceSheets?id='$id'> <i class='icon-eye-open'></i></a></td>"
```

to this:

```
echo "<td> <a href='account/practiceSheets?id=" . $row["id"] . "'> <i class='icon-eye-open'> </i> </a> </td>";
```

and got the desired results!